# Pulling info from two MYSQL tables using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Creating a lightweight budget app. I have one database, two tables.

TRANSACTIONS - date, amount, vendor, category_id (single digit)
CATEGORIES - id, name, limit (how much I can spend in each)

I'm currently using the PHP below to print the sum total of all transactions' amounts grouped by category. What I'm wanting to do is show each grouped total but also the corresponding "name" and "limit". I also would like to write the math so each "value_sum" is subtracted from "limit" and the difference is displayed.

Example:

Groceries -         Spent: -12.00       Limit: 200.00       Left: 188.00
Rent -          Spent: -3.00        Limit: 200.00       Left: 188.00
Eating Out -        Spent: -9.00        Limit: 200.00       Left: 188.00
Utilities -         Spent: -45.00       Limit: 200.00       Left: 188.00

```
<?php

$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(amount) AS value_sum FROM TRANSACTIONS group by category") 
or die(mysql_error());  

$number = value_sum;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

    echo "<div class='col1'>"; 
    echo round ($row['value_sum'], 2);
    echo "</div>"; 
} 


?>
```

Comment: `select category, sum(amount) ... group by category`... can't display what you ain't fetching.

Comment: So you obviously seem to understand that you need to pull data from both tables, but your example code does not show you making an attempt to do this at all.  Have you made an attempt to join the tables but have not been successful?  Can you show that attempt?

Comment: You say you have two **databases** (one named TRANSACTIONS) but then you `SELECT ... FROM TRANSACTIONS`.. did you mean two **tables**?

Comment: Yes. My mistake. One db, two tables.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but I guess a simple join would do the trick:

```
SELECT SUM(`t1`.`amount`) AS `value_sum`, `t2`.`name`, `t2`.`limit`
FROM `transactions` AS `t1`
JOIN `categories` AS `t2`
    ON `t1`.`category_id` = `t2`.`category`
GROUP BY `category`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
   SELECT 
    (select cat.name from CATEGORIES where cat.id = tran.category_id limit 1) as Categorie,
    SUM(tran.amount) as Spent,
    (select cat.limite from CATEGORIES where cat.id = tran.category_id limit 1) as Limite,
    (select cat.limite from CATEGORIES  
      where cat.id = tran.category_id limit 1)-(SUM(tran.amount)) AS Lefted 
    FROM TRANSACTIONS tran
    group by tran.category_id;
```

I change the limit var to limite, because it's a reserved word of mysql; i also use category_id just like in your tables description.

Comment: Ok. so this works! How then would I include the "name" of each budget in CATEGORIES? This is my latest code:  SELECT 
     
     (select name from CATEGORIES where id = tran.category_id limit 1) as Categorie,
     SUM(tran.amount) as Spent,
     
     (select limite from CATEGORIES where id = tran.category_id limit 1) as Limite,
     
     (select limite from CATEGORIES where id = tran.category_id limit 1)-(SUM(tran.amount)) AS Lefted 
     
     FROM TRANSACTIONS tran
     
     GROUP by tran.category_id;